# suggest a java based tool for developing calculations-intense application

Tags: java

We are having a proposal to develop a new application which has intense calculations. Its basically a score card/dash board application where the UI is developed in FLEX.

In the middleware the data will be read from Oracle and the calculations will be done. 
From the Oracle we will be only reading the data. There will be no write operations to the database.

there are many formulas which I'm not sure where to place.

As of now, the plan is to develop the services using Spring.(Container + Spring_JDBC)
and expose them as SOAP based webservices (using Axis).

I've developed applications like above. So, am thinking the same way. Can any one suggest any better approach?

Comment: Sounds like it'll work.  You've had experience with it.   This question seems too open ended to me.

Comment: @musicfreak: i was not sure how to present it. Anyways, modified.

Comment: What kind of calculations are you talking about. Elaborate what intense calclation means

Answer (score 0):

Try GWT. The whole stack will be in Java. GWT is also capable of building rich UI's and you can handle a lot of thing at the client layer itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to dispatch your intensive calculations on multiple hosts, you may want to have a look at the GridGain framework :
http://www.gridgain.com/product.html